# Using a C string gives a warning: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned"

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I am not a C programmer, so I am not that familiar with C-string, but now I have to use a C library, so here is a shortened version of my code to demonstrate my problem:

```
char** ReadLineImpl::my_completion () {
    char* matches[1];
    matches[0] = "add";

    return matches;
}
```

I am getting this warning:

> Warning - address of stack memory associated with local variable 'matches' returned

And my program does not seem to work properly (might be because of the above mentioned warning).

What does the warning imply? And will it cause any problems?

Comment: You're returning  the address to the first character pointer which is allocated on stack and which ceases to exist after you exit the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)*

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Variable `char* matches[1];` is declared on the stack, and it will be automatically released when the current block goes out of scope.

This means when you return `matches`, memory reserved for `matches` will be freed, and your pointer will point to something that you don't want to.

You can solve this in many ways, and some of them are:

1. Declare `matches[1]` as `static`: `static char* matches[1];` - this will allocate space for `matches` in the static space and not on the stack (this may bite you if you
   use it inappropriately, as all instances of the `my_completion` function will share the same `matches` variable).
2. Allocate space in the caller function, and pass it to the `my_completion` function: `my_completion(matches)`:

   ```
   char* matches[1];
   matches = my_completion(matches);

   // ...

   char** ReadLineImpl::my_completion (char** matches) {
        matches[0] = "add";

        return matches;
   }
   ```
3. Allocate space in the called function on the heap (using `malloc`, `calloc`, and friends) and pass the ownership to the caller function, which will have to deallocate this space when not needed any more (using `free`).

Comment: Thanks I got it. The worst thing is that this is the second time that get this kind of problem:) anyways, thank you very much

Comment: Assuming that it's the `GNU readline`, this will cause a crash, since `readline` will free the memory returned by the completion function.

Comment: @MatsPetersson This does seems like readline - and in that case you are right. I will upvote your answer!

Comment: declaring `matches` as `static` will allocate space on static space, not on heap.

Comment: Third option is allocate memory in heap by calling calloc

Answer (score 14):

When you return the `matches` array, you are returning the address of the first element. This is stored on the stack inside `my_completion`.

Once you return from `my_completion` that memory is reclaimed and will (most likely) eventually be reused for something else, overwriting the values stored in `matches` - and yes, that may well be why your application doesn't work - if it isn't right now, it probably will be once you have fixed some other problems, or changed it a bit, or something else, because this is not one of those little warnings that you can safely ignore.

You can fix this in a few different ways. The most obvious is to simply use `std::vector<char *>` [or better yet `std::vector<std::string>`] instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> ReadLineImpl::my_completion ()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("add");
    return strings;
}
```

So, if the library requires a `char **` as per the [`readline`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_45.html) interface, then use this:

```
char** ReadLineImpl::my_completion ()
{
    char **matches = static_cast<char **>malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
    matches[1] = "add";
    return matches;
}
```

Problem solved!

Comment: I would use a vector as a c++ programmer but the library demands char**, so then I have to convert to char**.

Comment: So, assuming you are using the `readline` interface, then you MUST allocate the memory with malloc, as `readline` frees it later. I will edit.

Comment: Good, just one thing, I had to use (char**)malloc(1 * sizeof(char *)) but thanks, your answer is better, though I am not gonna change

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the heap instead of the stack

It's better to allocate memory on the heap for **this case** by using:

```
int* someDataForParams(void *_params) {

    // ...

    int* charCounts = (int*) calloc(96, sizeof(char*));

    // ...

    return charCounts;
}
```

96 is just a string length (just a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))).

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

The first one is to declare the variable as a static variable with the keyword `static`.

And the second solution is to use dynamic allocation with `malloc` or `calloc`.