# Work around error 'Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned'

Tags: c, arrays, string, heap-memory, stack-memory

I am trying to call a method that will generate a **2D char array** (array of strings) and return it to be used in another function.

My example:

```
char ** example(void)
{
    char *test[3];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        test[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    }

    test[foo][bar] = 'baz'; // of course I would declare 'foo' and 'bar'
    // ...
    // ...

    return test;
}
```

And then I would like to be able to use the array as follows:

```
void otherMethod(void)
{
    char ** args = example();
    // do stuff with args
}
```

The problem is that this produces the **error**:

> warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'test' returned
>         [-Wreturn-stack-address]

I could solve this problem by defining `test` in the global scope as opposed to locally, but I would very much rather not do this as it seems messy, especially if I am to have several of these.

**Is there a way to create and return an array of strings in C without defining it globally?**

Comment: Same error message: *[Using C-string gives Warning: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041100/)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track. All you need to do is to change the allocation of the `test[3];` itself from automatic (aka "stack") to dynamic (aka "heap"):

```
char **test = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
```

This makes it legal to return `test` from your function, because it would no longer be returning an address associated with stack allocation.

Of course the caller would be required to `free` both the pointers inside the return, and the return itself. You may want to consider supplying a helper function for that.

Another approach would be to take `char test[]` as a function parameter:

```
void example(char *test[], size_t count) {
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
        test[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    }
    ...
    // return is not required
}
```

Now the caller would have to pass an array of suitable size into your function, so that you could avoid allocating it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `malloc`:

```
char ** example(void)
{
    char** test = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        test[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    }

    test[foo][bar] = 'baz'; // of course I would declare 'foo' and 'bar'
    // ...
    // ...

    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `static`:

```
static char *test[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly an addition to @dasblinkenlight's answer.

You write:

```
test[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

`test[i]` is now a char array that can contain a string of at most 2 characters and the terminating null. And you should load it that way:

```
strncpy(test[i], 2, str); /* where str is another char pointer */
```

So I would write:

```
test[i] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(test[i], "baz");
```

C strings can be confusing at first sight ;-)