# How could I make c return correct?

Tags: c++, class

```
MyVector &operator*(double b,  MyVector &a) {
  MyVector c(outN(a));
  c = a * b;
  return c;
}
```

Vscode showes me"Reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'c' returned".But I need c return.How should I do?

Comment: Don’t return a reference

Comment: Replace `MyVector &operator` with `MyVector operator`

Comment: Because `c` is declared inside this function, it's in the stack, which may be destroyed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using C-string: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041100/using-c-string-address-of-stack-memory-associated-with-local-variable-returned)

Comment: `operator*` is supposed to return a result by value, not by reference.