# valgrind conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized

Tags: c, valgrind

Valgrind is throwing two warning for two lines of codes, mentioned in the comments next to each.

**Warning 1**:

> invalid write of size 8, Address ... is 8 bytes inside a block of size
>   9 alloc'd

`data[size] = NULL;`

**Warning 2**:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized values(s)

```
for (char **ptr = data; *ptr; ptr++) { // warning -> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized values(s)
    free(*ptr);
}
```

---

Here's a complete code,

**Callee**

```
char **getList() {
    char **list = (char *[]) {"John", "Jane", NULL};

    int size = 0;
    for (char **ptr = list; *ptr; ptr++) {
        size++;
    }

    char **data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * size + 1);
    if (data == NULL) goto exception;

    for (int i = 0; *list; list++, i++) {
        data[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(*list) + 1));
        if (data[i] == NULL) goto exception;
        strcpy(data[i], *list);
    }

    data[size] = NULL; // this line gives warning
    // warning -> invalid write of size 8, Address ... is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
    return data;

    exception:
    fprintf(stderr, "data allocation failed.\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

**Caller** different file/scope

```
char **data = getList();

for (char **ptr = data; *ptr; ptr++) { // warning -> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized values(s)
    free(*ptr);
}
free(data);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char *) * size + 1` is not `sizeof(char *) * (size + 1)`

Comment: oh, that fixed the problems, i hope this is ok as well -> `(strlen(*list) + 1)`

Comment: Also do you see any other problem with the code, is it well written or do you see some improvements?

Comment: I would change `char **getList()` to `char **getList(void)` and `char **list = (char *[]){..` to `const char * const list[] = {...`. I would explicit test against `NULL` so `*list != NULL` and `*ptr != NULL`. And `strlen` + `strcpy` can be optimized to `strlen` + `memcpy`. Both `size` and `i` can't be negative - should use `unsigned`.

Comment: it gives me some error, because i'm incrementing `list++` in the second for loop, I'd love you to please review this code. Thanks. since I think it has bunch of hoops.

Comment: Maybe it's part of the exercise, but I would never clone the names to the heap unless (1) I intend to read them from an external data source, or (2) I intend to make direct modifications to the names (e.g. using `strtok`).

Comment: Ruud, yes caller is not modifying, but I though I shouldn't return an array without allocation (malloc). The error is fixed but can someone please update it for a better optimum solution?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added an answer based on the suggestions, can you please review. I didn't get you on the `strlen + memcpy`, need help with the code example please.

Comment: @AppDeveloper In your program, the strings `"John"` and `"Jane"` have a boundless lifetime. This explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533439/string-literals-vs-array-of-char-when-initializing-a-pointer

Comment: Ruud, so you mean I can just return `list` to the caller without allocation (that will be the address of stack memory), I'm not well versed with this, please guide more. I also posted an answer, please feel free to edit it and post as yours with amendments. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @RuudHelderman, I've edited my answer with version2, is this is what you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Writing based on the suggestions on a new slate.

**Edit** updated based on the comments.

```
char **getList(void) {
    const char * const list[] = {"John", "Jane", NULL};

    unsigned int size = 0;
    const char * const *ptr;
    for (ptr = list; *ptr != NULL; ptr++) {
        size++;
    }

    char **data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (size + 1));
    if (data == NULL) goto exception;

    ptr = list;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; *ptr != NULL; ptr++, i++) {
        const size_t cache = strlen(*ptr) + 1;
        data[i] = malloc(cache);
        if (data[i] == NULL) goto exception;
        memcpy(data[i], *ptr, cache);
    }

    data[size] = NULL;
    return data;

    exception:
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed.\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

---

**VERSION 2**

With the help of [Using C-string: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041100/using-c-string-address-of-stack-memory-associated-with-local-variable-returned)

```
const char * const *getList(void) {
    static const char * const list[] = {"John", "Jane", NULL};
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `ptr = (char **) list` ... use proper type`const char * const * ptr = list;`, too many `const` can get confusing. With `strlen + memcpy` I meant to cache the result of `strlen` so that `strcpy` won't have to iterate over the string again. `const size_t cache = strlen(*ptr) + 1; ... malloc(cache); ... memcpy(data[0], *ptr, cache);`

Comment: Updated, please review if everything's ok.

Comment: you mean `memcpy(data[i]`, not `data[0]`.?

Comment: @KamilCuk do you agree with version2?

Comment: Yes, I think I would merge it ; )

Comment: @KamilCuk, I even tried to do a one-liner (no declaration, return inline), simply return the array as it is with a cast but doesn't seem like i've a way, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, for a hard-coded, read-only list, version 2 will do fine. And if you'd like it to be a one-liner, then just get rid of `getList` and let the caller directly refer to `list`. BTW, in version 2, please do not `free`.

Comment: Thanks, getting rid of the function is not possible (because it has multiple callers), although i confirm, list is readonly and hard coded. was wondering if i could shorten the the function to one line, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not tested. My recommendations are

- Use strdup
- Use calloc
- Try to avoid using goto

  char **getList() {
      char **list = (char *[]) {"John", "Jane", NULL};

  ```
  // this size is a compile time constant, no need to
  calculate it at runtime
  size_t size = sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]);

  // using calloc initializes everything to 0/NULL
  // -> no need to set the last element then
  char **data = calloc(sizeof(char *), size);

  // don't use goto
  if (data != NULL)
  {
      for (size_t i = 0U; i < size; i++)
      {
          if (list[i] != NULL)
          {
              // don't re-invent the wheel with strlen/memcpy
              // just use strdup
              data[i] = strdup(list[i]);
              if (data[i] == NULL) goto exception;
          }
      }
      return data;
  }

  exception:
  // you need to do more cleanup here
  // for instance if the 'data' calloc succeeds, the "John" strdup succeeds
  // but the "Jane" strdup fails then you have two leaks. That said fixing
  // small leaks when you are out of memory usually isn't your biggest issue.
  fprintf(stderr, "data allocation failed.\n");
  return NULL;
  ```

  }