# Getting Segmentation Fault in C when using sleep with Pthreads

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, sleep

I am creating a thread in C with PThreads which executes a function that is running in an infinit loop and prints some random json string every second into the console. At the beginning he prints the result of the function simulateLED with no problem, but after sleeping for 1 second, I'll get a Segmentation Fault (Core dumped). If I remove sleep, I'll not get it and the program works fine. Why do I get a Segmentation Fault with sleeping and how to fix it?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *simulateLED() {
    int temp;
    int luftf;
    char* jsonString;

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    int x=-10, y=50;
    temp=(rand()%((y+1)-x))+x;

    x=2, y=30;
    luftf=(rand()%((y+1)-x))+x;

    printf("%d %d\n", temp, luftf);
    fflush(stdout);

    sprintf(jsonString, "{\n\"TEMP\": %d,\n\"HUMI\": %d\n}", temp, luftf);

    return jsonString;
}
void *simAndSendThread(void *param) {
    while(1) {
        printf("%s", simulateLED());
        sleep(1);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread;

    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, simAndSendThread, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(pthread_join(thread, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never assign `jsonString` a value. You pass its garbage value to `sprintf`, which can't be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidSchwartz has pointed out, the reason for the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error is related to the `jsonString` pointer, that is currently not initialized (i.e., not *pointing* to anything). Hence, `sprintf` is writing to a random location, which might or might not work at times.

In order to fix it, you can statically assign space to the `jsonString` variable when you declare it, such as:

```
...
char jsonString[256];
...
```

This implies that you can have a string up to `255` characters (`1` extra character reserved for `\0`). Alternatively, you can dynamically allocate the space using `malloc`:

```
...
char *jsonString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);

// Your code here

free(jsonString);
...
```

In this case, you must remember to release the allocation at the end of your function using `free`, otherwise you will leak memory. In case you haven't learned about dynamic memory yet, see [When and why to use malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800482/when-and-why-to-use-malloc).

P.S.: If you are on Linux, I strongly recommend to use `valgrind` when you have memory-related errors. This tool will most probably hint where did you made the mistake. Check the [Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated memory to `jsonString` and still trying to do `sprintf` and after return `print`

Try this

```
char* jsonString;
    jsonString = malloc( 1024 );
```

And don't forget to `free` once done, you are using a `while(1)` and if you don't `free` there is every chance that you'll hit the *out of memory* error very soon.

If you `enable full warnings` you should have received a `warning message for uninitialized variable` for which eventually would have avoided all the crahes.