# How to write an array of dynamic size with preprocessors in c?

Tags: c

I'm studying the preprocessors and got stuck with arrays. I use below preprocessor to initialise an array containing pre defined values.

```
#ifndef ARRAY
#define ARRAY
    const char arr[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,80};
#endif
```

But their comes a problem. I want to take user input in that array. So, how can I write an array of dynamic size with preprocessor so that I can also take user input in it.

I've tried this but it gives me an error.

```
#define n 0

#ifndef ARRAY
#define ARRAY
    const char arr[n] {};
#endif
```

Comment: Preprocessor is compile time, user input is runtime. You cannot design something static that relies on information you get at runtime

Comment: But i just want to initialize array in preprocessor, and then the array will take user input during runtime (like function declaration). Is it not possible?

Comment: What does the preprocessor have to do with any of this?

Comment: Not without dynamic memory allocation. static arrays arep placed on the stack, allocated memory on the heap. You can't dynamically initialize stuff on the stack. For stack allocation, the entire size of what needs to be placed there has to be known at compile time.

Comment: Maybe right, but still, compile time allocation with a variable as the size is not supported, at least in C. In C#, it is.

Comment: @Psi If you're talking about `int n = get_user_input(); char arr[n];`, that absolutely is supported.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe C99 got rid of more limitations than I expected.

Comment: You can use malloc  function for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: thanks @Psi , i got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocessor is going to happen once, before compiling, so you will have to figure out the maximum size of the array beforehand, in order to set a fix size, [like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c9r4QffYRyexHLzb).

Otherwise, you will have to use the [heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800482/when-and-why-to-use-malloc) (malloc or realloc) or [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)  to create an array whose size depends on the user(in your particular case) at runtime.

Comment: Can you give me an example with a code? I'm a bit confused.