# Header File: From Namespaces to Classes to Functions

Tags: c++

I am struggling a little bit with a project I have and am in need of some serious help. For now, I just want to be led on the right path and will follow up with any more questions I have regarding the project. Also, I am using Visual Studios. :)

Alright, so I am supposed to implement a `list` class within a namespace `lib`. This is all supposed to be defined within a header file. The `list` class will implement a variable-sized array where memory management within the class methods will be performed. The `list` class shall contain the private member `double* _data` which will be the array of floating point values.

The `list` must be default constructible. This constructor shall set `list::_data` equal to `nullptr` and the size of the list to 0 (there is no data stored).
The `list` must also be constructible with a parameterized constructor accepting an `unsigned integer` parameter (reference as `N` herein) denoting the intended size of the array. The constructor shall allocate an array of size `N` and set the size to be `N`.

I'm fairly new to C++, so I am still trying to wrap my head around everything. However, here is my header file so far:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

namespace lib {
    class list {
    private:
        double* _data;
        list() {        //default constructor
            list::_data = nullptr;
        }

        list(unsigned int n) {      //contructor
            //array size = unsigned int n

        }
    };
}

#endif
#pragma once
```

I want to make sure I am on the right path so far, but need help allocating memory. Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, to dynamically allocate memory use `malloc` and then `free` the memory after you are done with it.

```cpp
_data = (double*) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
```

[When and why to use malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800482/when-and-why-to-use-malloc)

[How do free and malloc work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957099/how-do-free-and-malloc-work-in-c)

You can free the data in the list deconstructor

```cpp
~list() { free(_data); }
```

In c++ you also have access to `new` and `delete`.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-and-delete-operators-in-cpp-for-dynamic-memory/

```cpp
_data = new double[n];
```

```cpp
~list() { delete[] _data; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are building a linked list.
This page shows a basic linked list setup if you get stuck:
https://www.learn-cpp.org/en/Linked_lists

Also, if you need to have a separate header and .cpp file

the header definitions would look like:

list();    or    void add(double n);

the .cpp implementations would look like:

list::list() {//constructor}    or    void list::add(double n) {//add to list stuff}