# Dynamic Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using an array and I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char **q = (char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char*));
q[0]="So Many Books";
q[1]="So Many Books";
q[2]="So Many Books";
q[3]="So Many Books";
q[4]="So Many Books";
printf("%s\n",q[0]);
printf("%s\n",q[1]);
printf("%s\n",q[2]);
printf("%s\n",q[3]);
printf("%s\n",q[4]);
return 0;
}
```

Why is the compiler not giving me an error here?
I only have booked a place for one string out of an array of strings.

I have looked to some resources like:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDVC3wKjS64
- [Dynamic memory allocation for pointer arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068643/dynamic-memory-allocation-for-pointer-arrays)

Comment: There's no syntax errors, so no compiler errors. In `c`, memory management is up to the programmer. Sounds like you already know your code is rife with UB.

Comment: You're a C programmer.  You're assumed to know what you're doing.  If you want hand-holding, choose a different language.  That makes it tough on beginners in particular, but the mindset is "the programmer knows what they're doing", even when it is manifest that they don't.

Comment: Why are you casting the result of `malloc` to `char *`, when you need a `char **`? Why are you casing the result of `malloc` at all???

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that you haven't allocated enough memory; that's a problem that doesn't show up until compile time. A sufficiently clever compiler *might* be able to figure it out, but in general the argument passed to `malloc` needn't be a compile-time constant, and it's not possible to detect this kind of error in all cases.

Comment: is not about handd-holding ,, but should't stop ?cus i am assigning in un booked place ?

Comment: I just noticed the incorrect cast. You're initializing a `char**` object with a `char*` value. The types are not compatible and are not implicitly convertible. A conforming compiler must at least warn you about that. Did you get a warning that you didn't tell us about? A helpful idiom is this: `char **q = malloc(N * sizeof *q);`

Comment: @Salman: As I said, it cannot in general be detected at compile time. Detecting it at run time would require the compiler to add code to do the checking, slowing down the normal case.

Comment: Actually, best case, you have allocated an array of pointers that may eventually be able to hold strings.  Each array also needs to be allocated - or you need to get a bit more creative overlaying a buffer onto a single alloc.  (As a rule, I hate 2-dim dynamic arrays in C - it just is too easy to screw things up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why is the compiler not giving me an error here*

Simply because, the issue here is not related to any syntactical error, it's a logical error that is beyond the jurisdiction of a compiler-error-check.

The problem here is, apart from index 0, any other index is out of bound access here. There is nothing in C standard to *stop* you from doing that, but accessing out of bound memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), hence the program output is also, undefined. Anything could happen. Just don't do that.

Remember, just because you *can* do something (write code to access out of bound memory) does not mean you *should* be doing that.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).