# Invalid write of size 8, C Valgrind, string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, valgrind

I have been using both valgrind and gdb and I can not quite figure out what the problem is. It hops around too much for me to really trace it down in gdb, and in valgrind I don't have enough information. Here is my makeargv function, which is putting strings outputted from strtok() into arrays. makeargv is called from the below parse function. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I would really appreciate the help :D.

Just an FYI I'm really new to all this malloc'ing and don't really understand the concept as well as I would like. I'm not sure when specifically I should be mallocing. I feel like since here I am mainly setting constant values I don't have to be, but I'm wondering why it won't work.

makeargv function

```
int makeargv(const char *string, char **argvp) {
    int i = 0;
    int numtokens = 0;
    const char *copy;
    char *buffer = malloc(160*sizeof(char));

    if ((string == NULL) || (delims == NULL) || (argvp == NULL)) {
      return -1;
    }

    argvp = NULL;
    copy = string + strspn(string, delims);
    if ((buffer = malloc(strlen(copy) + 1)) == NULL) {
      return -1;
    }
    strcpy(buffer, copy);
    numtokens = 0;
    if (strtok(buffer, delims) != NULL) {
      for (numtokens = 1; strtok(NULL, delims) != NULL; numtokens++);
    }

    if ((argvp = malloc((numtokens + 2)*sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
      free(buffer);
      return -1;
    }

    if (numtokens == 0) {
      free(buffer);
    }
    else {
      strcpy(buffer, copy);
      *argvp = malloc(16);
      *argvp = strtok(buffer, delims);

      for (i = 2; i < (numtokens*2); i += 2) {
      *(argvp + i) = strtok(NULL, delims);
      //printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, delims)); /*When I run this the tokens come out
      correctly so I know it isn't a problem with strtok */
  }
}

//  *((argvp) + numtokens) = NULL;
free(buffer);
return numtokens;
}
```

Parse function

```
void parse_file(char* filename) {
    char* line = malloc(160*sizeof(char));
    FILE* fp = file_open(filename);
    int i = 0;

    while((line = file_getline(line, fp)) != NULL) {
      char** results = malloc(16*10*sizeof(char));

      if (strlen(line) == 1){
        continue;
      }

      if ((i = makeargv(line, results)) == -1){
        printf("ERROR SOMEWHERE IN MAKEARGV");
        continue;
      } 
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(line);
}
```

valgrind output

```
==7309== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7309== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7309== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7309== Command: ./custmake
==7309== 
==7309== Invalid write of size 8
==7309==    at 0x400C23: makeargv (main.c:62)
==7309==    by 0x400CD4: parse_file (main.c:120)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309==  Address 0x51f25c0 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 20 alloc'd
==7309==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x400B76: makeargv (main.c:49)
==7309==    by 0x400CD4: parse_file (main.c:120)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309== 
==7309== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7309==    at 0x4C2BFC2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x4EA2CEB: puts (ioputs.c:37)
==7309==    by 0x400D09: parse_file (main.c:128)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309== 
==7309== Invalid read of size 1
==7309==    at 0x4C2BFC2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x4EA2CEB: puts (ioputs.c:37)
==7309==    by 0x400D09: parse_file (main.c:128)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7309== 
==7309== 
==7309== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7309==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==7309==    at 0x4C2BFC2: __GI_strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x4EA2CEB: puts (ioputs.c:37)
==7309==    by 0x400D09: parse_file (main.c:128)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7309==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7309==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7309==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7309==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7309== 
==7309== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7309==     in use at exit: 1,084 bytes in 6 blocks
==7309==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 1 frees, 1,100 bytes allocated
==7309== 
==7309== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==7309==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x400BCB: makeargv (main.c:59)
==7309==    by 0x400CD4: parse_file (main.c:120)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309== 
==7309== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 6
==7309==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x400B76: makeargv (main.c:49)
==7309==    by 0x400CD4: parse_file (main.c:120)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309== 
==7309== 160 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==7309==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7309==    by 0x400A6E: makeargv (main.c:32)
==7309==    by 0x400CD4: parse_file (main.c:120)
==7309==    by 0x400DFF: main (main.c:172)
==7309== 
==7309== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7309==    definitely lost: 196 bytes in 3 blocks
==7309==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7309==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7309==    still reachable: 888 bytes in 3 blocks
==7309==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7309== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==7309== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==7309== 
==7309== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7309== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7309== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963780/when-should-i-use-malloc-in-c-and-when-dont-i

Comment: Note: you have a helluva memory leak in that function. You will leak the 160-char allocation with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Yeah I plan to fix a lot of memory leaks. I see tons of stuff that could be out, but I'm just making sure that EVERYTHING is allocated SOMETHING beforehand, because when I don't it seems to do weird stuff. I just want to know why with everything having ample and plentiful memory it can't find space at all for anything.

Answer (score 17):

Your `argvp` variable in `makeargv` is an array of pointers, but when you allocate he memory for it you use `sizeof(int)` which will only be four bytes on a 64 bit system, while pointers will be 8 bytes.

As a result you write beyond the end of the array - that's why it reports you writing 8 bytes at offset 16 of a 20 byte block, which therefore overlaps the end of the block by 4 bytes.

Use `sizeof(char *)` to get the correct size of a pointer when allocating the `argvp` array.