# Cannot change character in char array

Tags: c, malloc, free

According to this question: [When should I use malloc in C and when don't I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963780/when-should-i-use-malloc-in-c-and-when-dont-i)

Using malloc to allocate memory should allow me to change one of the characters in the array.  However, this program crashes at run time.  Can someone please advise? (also `free(ptr)` causes a different crash which is why it is commented out).

```
char* ptr;
ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char[10]));
ptr = "hello";
ptr[0] = 'H';
printf("The string contains: %s\n", ptr);
//free (ptr);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program crashes because this line

```
ptr = "hello";
```

completely undoes the effect of `malloc` from the previous line:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char[10])); // No need to cast to char*
```

and it also creates a memory leak along the way, because the address returned by `malloc` is irrecoverably lost after the assignment.

Once the assignment is done, an attempt to set `ptr[0] = 'H'` results in a crash, because you are trying to modify the memory of the string literal itself - i.e. undefined behavior.

In C strings need to be copied, not assigned if you want to modify them later. Replace the assignment with `strcpy` call to fix this problem.

```
strcpy(ptr, "hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that need to be fixed:

```
char* ptr = 0;
ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
if(!ptr)
    return 0; // or something to indicate "memory allocation error"
strcpy(ptr, "hello");
ptr[0] = 'H';
printf("The string contains: %s\n", ptr);
free (ptr);
return 0;
```

This compiles and runs correctly in main()

Comment: you should explain why instead of just posting code

Comment: yes, but I saw dasblinkenlight's answer after I had written mine, so I felt there was no need to improve my answer anymore. I could have deleted it, but I left it because of the `malloc` return value check.