# Segmentation fault in C program using pointers as parameters

Tags: c

Im trying to understand **pointers** as function **parameters**, and in one of the programs there is a segmentation error I can't fix. Firstly, why to use pointers in function arguments? and Why is this error showing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void square_it(int* a)
{
  printf("The final value is: %d\n", *a * *a);
}

int main()
{
  int* input;

  puts("This program squares the input integer number");
  puts("Please put the number:");

  scanf("%d", &input);

  square_it(input);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* input;` does not allocate memory for an `int` - it mearly makes it possible to make `input` point at an `int` (allocated elsewhere). Currently, by dereferencing it, you make your program have undefined behavior. On that note, turn on more compiler warnings. If you use `gcc` or `clang` you would benefit from using `-Wall -Wextra`. You can also add `-pedantic-errors` if you want to learn C without the extras added by the vendors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allocating and initialising a pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848594/allocating-and-initialising-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int* input;` does not allocate memory for an `int`. It mearly makes it possible to make `input` point at an `int` (allocated elsewhere). Currently, by dereferencing it (like you do with `*a`), you make your program have *undefined behavior*. If you really want an intermediate pointer variable for this, this example shows how it could be done:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void square_it(int *a) {
    *a *= *a;     // same as  *a = *a * *a;
}

int main() {
    int data;
    int* input = &data; // now `input` points at an  `int`

    puts("This program squares the input integer number");
    puts("Please put the number:");

    // check that `scanf` succeeds:
    if(scanf("%d", input) == 1) { // don't take its address, it's a pointer already
        square_it(input);
        // since `input` is pointing at `data`, it's actually the value of `data`
        // that is affected by `scanf` and `square_it`, which makes the below work:
        printf("The final value is: %d\n", data);
    }
}
```

Without an intermediate pointer variable:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void square_it(int *a) {
    *a *= *a;
}

int main() {
    int input; // note that it's not a pointer here

    puts("This program squares the input integer number");
    puts("Please put the number:");

    if(scanf("%d", &input) == 1) { // here, taking the address of `input` makes sense
        square_it(&input);         // and here too
        printf("The final value is: %d\n", input);
    }
}
```

Without any pointers at all, it could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int square_it(int a) {
    return a * a;
}

int main() {
    int input;

    puts("This program squares the input integer number");
    puts("Please put the number:");

    if(scanf("%d", &input) == 1) { // here, taking the address of `input` makes sense
        int result = square_it(input);
        printf("The final value is: %d\n", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void square_it(int* a)
{
  printf("The final value is: %d\n", *a * *a);
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int* input = &i;

  puts("This program squares the input integer number");
  puts("Please put the number:");

  scanf("%d", input);

  square_it(input);
  return 0;
}
```

There are some errors in the original code:

According to the man-pages to `scanf`, it takes a format string and then the address of where to store the input.

You gave it the address of a pointer (eg. an `int**`), which is not what scanf expects.

Also you need to provide memory to store the input in. The `scanf` string tells that you want an integer as input. In the above code snippet that is `i`.

`input` points to `i`, so i can give the `int*`, that is `input` to `scanf`. `scanf` will then write into `i`. We can then go ahead and put the address of `i` into the `sqare_it` function.

Since we did not use the heap, we don't need to worry about memory management.