# Should pthread function arguments be allocated on the stack or the heap?

Tags: c, pthreads, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've written a "solution" to the producer-consumer/bounded-buffer problem using pthreads, and I use a 72 bit struct to store the data and synchronization types which are shared by all of the threads. This struct is allocated on the heap, but allocating it on the stack and passing its address in `pthread_create` also works. Is there any reason to prefer stack allocation over heap allocation (or vice versa) of pthread arguments in cases where `pthread_detach` is *not* used?

Edit:
The struct is declared within `main()`, and all threads are guaranteed to finish before `main()` is finished. Going out of scope is not an issue.

Comment: I doubt it, just be wary of data scope when passing the argument from the stack. If your data from the stack goes out of scope (when the function exits for instance), and your threads are still working on it .. UB

Comment: given your edit, sounds like your question has more to do with when to use automatic vs dynamic storage allocation. Given the small size of your data structure, I'd use automatic. Here's one of a few questions on SO dealing with that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963780/when-should-i-use-malloc-in-c-and-when-dont-i

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.2.4 Storage durations of objects 5 An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class
specifier static has automatic storage duration, as do some compound literals. The
result of attempting to indirectly access an object with automatic storage duration from a
thread other than the one with which the object is associated is implementation-defined.*

Comment: @EOF This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the lifetime of the stack allocated variables in relation to the running threads.

If the threads are guaranteed to exit before the stack variables go out of scope (i.e. you call `pthread_join` on all waiting threads) then using local variables is fine.  If stack variables go out of scope while the threads are still running, then you would have to dynamically allocate them.

Comment: Additionally, if different threads need different values for their control arguments, make sure that each thread gets its own argument to look at.  One of the commoner mistakes is to pass the same variable (local stack or heap) to each thread, giving each thread a different value in some element of the variable — which leads to confusion because the scheduling of the threads is not deterministic and multiple threads may see the same value, leading to chaos.