# when to use malloc() for memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm super new to C and currently I'm reading a textbook on C. In the textbook, while explaining what malloc is they provided a code snippet demonstrating the use of malloc.

```
1 int noOfstudents;
2     printf("how many students??");
3     scanf("%d",&noOfstudents);
4     int *studentCount=(int*)malloc(noOfstudents*(sizeof(int)));
5     if (studentCount==NULL){
6         fprintf(stderr,"memory allocation failed bro\n");
7         return 1;
8     }
9     for (int i = 0; i < noOfstudents; i++)
10      {
11        studentCount[i]=i+1;
12        printf("Student %d count: %d\n", i + 1, studentCount[i]);
13     }
      
15    free(studentCount);
```

We are using malloc here since we dont know the number of students for our array at compile-time.

But instead of using malloc, i could've replaced lines 4-7 (i.e whole malloc code) and replaced it with
`int studentCount[noOfstudents]` and it would correctly work. This works since at runtime when user input is received it is passed at parameter for initializing the array.
How is this different than malloc, I mean is there a scope difference, diff placement of memory block(stack, heap etc)? Also please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Variable length arrays are optional for C implementation (as in your proposed solution). In addition they aren't suitable for large allocations, as they usually using stack space, which is limited.

Comment: `malloc()` is required if the array needs to persist after the function returns. If it's just used temporarily during the function, you usually use a local array unless the size is large.

Comment: @Barmar Hi thanks for the reply. So basically if i need global scope for my array I use malloc.
But if i need local/function scope I can create a local array just as I did.

Comment: worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800482/when-and-why-to-use-malloc

Comment: It's not about scope, it's about timing. You can pass a local array to another function that you call, but you can't return it from the function.

Comment: also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963780/when-should-i-use-malloc-in-c-and-when-dont-i

Comment: Re “So basically if i need global scope for my array I use malloc”: No. Scope is about **where** in source code an **identifier** (name) is usable. Lifetime is **when** during program execution an **object** exists (has memory reserved for it). Also, C has no global scope. It has file scope with external linkage. Global scope would mean an identifier can be declared once and be visible throughout the program, but C does not have that. You have to declare an identifier in each file (translation unit) in which it is used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil " Global scope would mean an identifier can be declared once and be visible throughout the program, but C does not have that." I have a question regarding this, the constants that we declare using #define in our source file are visible throughout the code right? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm super new to C.
Thanks!

Comment: @karan: Macro names defined with `#define` are only visible in the translation unit (file being compiled along with everything it included). They are not visible in other translation units unless also defined in them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ohh ok ok. that clears it. Thanks!